# MS Access SQL Query to Populate Combo Box List of Values

Tags: ms-access

I have a database that schedules teachers to deliver lectures that range from 15 minutes to 4 hours long.  Many of these lectures take place simultaneously.  Some lectures require multiple teachers to deliver due to complexity of the subject.  These lectures cover topics that are categorized in one of ten areas of specialization.  We have ten teams whose members are experts in one of the ten areas of specialization.  Each team is responsible for delivering the lectures that are associated with their area of specialization.

Teachers are assigned to a team based on their chosen area of specialization and expertise.  Teachers must pass a certification course in order to be allowed to teach in an associated area of specialization.

Some teachers have multiple certifications and as a result can be scheduled to deliver lectures that are not the responsibility of the team to which they are assigned.  However, they only fill in in this capacity if all teachers from the team with responsibility for the lecture in question are busy and no one else can be assigned the lecture.

Teachers earn sick and vacation time and they can use this time as needed.  In addition, teachers are from time to time required to participate in professional development events or attend meetings.  Therefore, they are not always available to deliver lectures.

My task has been to develop a process where teachers can be scheduled to deliver lectures based on their certifications, team membership, and availability.

I have the following tables:
   Instructor lecture assignments (which instructors have been assigned to which lecture)
   Lecture schedule (name, date, start time, end time, certifications required for each lecture)
   Teacher not available (teacher name, date unavailable, start time unavailable, end time of unavailability)
   Teacher teams (names of teacher teams)
   Teachers (first, middle, last name of each teacher)
   Teacher certifications (name of each certification that can be earned by each teacher)
   Teacher certification conferrals (which teachers have earned which certifications and on what date)
   Teacher team assignments (which teachers are on which team)

The issue that I am trying to resolve is how to structure a query that will display, for each lecture, the teachers that are CURRENTLY certified to deliver that lecture, a member of the team that is responsible for that lecture, NOT unavailable due to professional development nor being assigned to deliver another simultaneously occurring lecture.

Can someone help me to understand how to structure this needed query, please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is take it one step at a time. Forget:

"for each lecture, the teachers that are CURRENTLY certified to deliver that lecture, a member of the team that is responsible for that lecture, NOT unavailable due to professional development nor being assigned to deliver another simultaneously occurring lecture."

Start with:

- List all teachers
- List all teacher certifications with their start and/or end dates. Your wording does not make it clear if by "currently" you mean "has not expired" which is what the assumption is reading the word currently, or "has already earned it" which is what your description of your data indicates, or both.
- Filter the above with the certification required by each lecture
- Filer by each reason for unavailability

One step at a time, you can't solve the problem in one go. It is ok if you take a wrong turn or end up with some extra queries that are unneeded, you can clean up when the goal has been reached.